# Regular expression for specific characters

Tags: java, regex

I've been building this regular expression  for a while and so far I've had not much luck. Anyways the regular expression is supposed to catch the following characters:
{}[]+-*/,.();

The boolean expression below works fine except when it encounters a ')'

```
atom.matches("\\[\\+\\-\\*/,.\\(\\)\\}\\{\\};");
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String))

Comment: Note that `matches()` tries matching the *whole* string, not just a substring.

Comment: @Joey I know, the string that I want to match is always one character. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a character class:

```
[{}[\]+*/,.()-]
```

More info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to compile. It seems to throw an error message with the \ saying that it is an invalid escape sequence.

Comment: If you're defining this inside of a String literal, you will probably need to escape the backslash itself. E.g., `"[{}[\\]+*/,.()-]"`